# How to recover data after unlocking bootloader

Tags: data-recovery

So guys I unlocked my bootloader and installed lineage os  1 month ago and before unlocking I forgot to create a backup and all data was erased so I saw a way to recover data in a rooted moto g here in some threads so can it be possible for my phone.my phone is  xaomi note 10 pro indian variant

Comment: Simple answer - no way